# Assuming variable is plus or minus 1

Tags: assumptions

I have a long calculation that I am doing, which involves a particular variable h, which in the end, is either +1 or -1.  (I would like a general result that is true for both cases.)  Since h only takes these values, h^2 = h^4 = h^6 ... = 1, and h^3 = h^5 = ... = h.  It would greatly simplify things if Mathematica could make use of these; thus, I would like to tell Mathematica to assume h^2 = 1.

However, if I do, e.g.,

```
Simplify[h^2, h^2 = 1]
```

I get the errors

```
Set::write: Tag Power in h^2 is Protected. >>
Simplify::bass: 1 is not a well-formed assumption. >>
```

If I try:

```
Simplify[h^2, h\[Element]{-1,1}]
```

It returns just h^2, not 1.

If I try:

```
Simplify[h^2, h=1 || h=-1]
```

then I get the errors:

```
Set::write: Tag Or in 1||h is Protected. >>
Simplify::bass: -1 is not a well-formed assumption. >>
```

How can I tell Mathematica to use the assumption that h^2 = 1?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try `Simplify[h^2, h^2 == 1]` There is an important difference between Set (i.e., `=`) and Equals (i.e. `==`)

Comment: @bill s: Thanks!  I don't know why that didn't occur to me.

Comment: The one that really throws people is SameQ (i.e., `===`)

Answer (score 1):

Since the expression isn't guaranteed to have a unique value in general when the input variables can have multiple discrete values, we have to use an approach that can give you **all possible** results. This can be done with `Reduce` instead of `Simplify`. Here are two examples:

```
expression /. 
 List@ToRules[
   Reduce[Join[{expression == a b + a b^2 + a^2 b}, 
     Map[#^2 == 1 &, {a, b}]]]]

(* ==> {-1, -1, -1, 3} *)
```

This is a list of all possible outcomes for the `expression` under the assumption that both `a` and `b` can be $\pm 1$. A more interesting special relation is this:

```
expression /. 
 List@ToRules[
   Reduce[Join[{expression == a b + a y + x b - x y}, 
     Map[#^2 == 1 &, {a, b, x, y}]]]]

(* ==> {-2, -2, -2, 2, -2, 2, 2, 2, -2, 2, 2, 2, -2, -2, -2, 2} *)
```

Here we have four variables with value $\pm 1$, and the value of the expression turns out to always be $\pm 2$. If you want to know what combinations of inputs belong to which outputs, you can leave out the `expression/.` part at the beginning.

If you only want to know the set of possible outputs, you can wrap the above in `DeleteDuplicates[...]`.